# Is it possible to pass a PID variable as a parameter into a crontab?

Tags: centos-7, crontab, pid

Is it possible to pass a PID variable as a parameter into a crontab:

`0 * * * * JETTYPID=$(ps aux | grep "jetty92.state" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')`

OR

Could I just define the variable at the top of the crontab as such:

`JETTYPID=$(ps aux | grep "jetty92.state" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')`

In order to capture a PID and then run a cron below and use that variables value in the command

`0 * * * * ~/jetty_trace.sh $JETTYPID`

The goal is to store the current PID for jetty into that variable and then use that variable as an arguement for a script that runs (in a nutshell)

`jstack -F <PID> >> stacktrack.log`

But with a bunch of date/time formatting. Is this possible?

Comment: You are using a very long alternative to `$(pidof jetty92.state)`. If you set `JETTYPID` anywhere other than in the run string, then you can't be sure that it hasn't been updated before you run `jstack`.

Comment: Good to know there's any easier way. Thanks :)

Comment: Why not incorporate this code into `jstack` itself, so that your `crontab` entry simply becomes `jstack >> stacktrack.log`? Or, if you can't modify `jstack`, then call a front end in `crontab`, eg  `pjstack >> stacktrack.log`, where `pjstack` verifies that `JETTYPID=$(pidof jetty92.state)` holds a single, valid PID, then runs `exec jstack -F $JETTYPID` (no redirection, since this is already done in `crontab`).